# What can I substitute for ragu in kosher lasgne?

Tags: substitutions, italian-cuisine, kosher

Most lasagne recpies ask for ragu and bechamel. Since I am cooking kosher, what can I substitute for ragu?

Comment: It can be easier to modify or substitute the bechamel. Either make it with a nut milk, or use a veloute, or use something else entierly (although the ideas for "something else entirely" are frequently also milk based, like a mascarpone lasagna)

Comment: Just don't use the bechamel.

Comment: Probably better to focus on the ragu, since there are often other cheeses in a lasagna recipe.

Answer (score 4):

You can either substitute the bechamel or the ragu:

**Bechamel**

- Use soy or almond milk and vegan butter
- Ideas:

  > - http://www.onegreenplanet.org/vegan-food/how-to-make-classic-sauces-vegan/
  > - https://realfood.tesco.com/recipes/dairy-free-bechamel-sauce.html

**Ragu**

- Simple.. just use vegetarian mince:

  > - https://www.quorn.co.uk/products/meat-free-mince
  > - https://www.morningstarfarms.com/products/morningstar-farms-meal-starters-grillers-recipe-crumbles-product.html

Both are listed as kosher.

Additional ideas/answers already posted here: [What can I substitute for dairy products in kosher meat dishes?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3486/what-can-i-substitute-for-dairy-products-in-kosher-meat-dishes?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

I'd personally just go with a mushroom ragu.

You can find plenty of recipes online, such as from [Serious Eats](https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2015/05/mushroom-ragu-sauce-recipe.html) or the [New York Times](https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1015828-mushroom-ragout).

I can't remember if fish counts as "meat" for Kosher rules, so you may need to avoid recipes that call for fish sauce or Worcestershire sauce.